# Is there a way to send an object via UITapGestureRecognizer?

Tags: ios, uiview, uitapgesturerecognizer

I have an object created from a class of type UIView to produce an unlimited number of views which then appear in smaller sizes in the middle of the screen. I used UITapGestureRecognizer to enlarge one of the views to fit the screen but the issue here is that the object is only usable within the first class and cannot be transferred to the second class which is the selector. 
What are your suggestions regarding this particular issue? 
How can I send my object to the selector to be able to use it there?
Thank you

Here is the first class which creates the object (derived from iCarousel) :

```
- (UIView *)carousel:(iCarousel *)carousel viewForItemAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index reusingView:(UIView *)view
{
    UILabel *label = nil;
    UIButton *close = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];


    //create new view if no view is available for recycling
    if (view == nil)
    {


        view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320.0f, 460.0f)];
        view.contentMode = UIViewContentModeCenter;

        view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

        label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, -100, 100, 100)];
        label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
        label.font = [label.font fontWithSize:50];
        label.tag = 1;
        [view addSubview:label];

        close.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 30);
        [close setTitle:@"x" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        close.titleLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:25];
        [close addTarget:self action:@selector(closeMe:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

        [view addSubview:close];


        UITapGestureRecognizer* tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapToMaximize:)];
        tap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
        [view addGestureRecognizer:tap];

    }
    else
    {

        //get a reference to the label in the recycled view
        label = (UILabel *)[view viewWithTag:1];

    }


    label.text = [items[index] stringValue];

    return view;
}
```

And the selector:

```
- (void)tapToMaximize:(UITapGestureRecognizer*)recognizer {

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3
                          delay:0
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear
                     animations:^{
                         carousel.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1, 1);

                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                     }];

}
```

So instead of using "carousel" which represents all the views, I want to use "view" so that I can only enlarge the current view and not all of them.

Comment: Can you post code showing how you set this up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`UITapGestureRecognizer` inherits the `view` property from `UIGestureRecognizer`, which you can use to enlarge just that tap gesture recognizer's view:

```
- (void)tapToMaximize:(UITapGestureRecognizer*)recognizer {

    UIView *viewToMaximize;
    if ([recognizer.view isEqual:_maximizedView]) {
        viewToMaximize = nil;
    } else {
        viewToMaximize = recognizer.view;
    }
    UIView *viewToUnmaximize = _maximizedView; // _maximizedView should be an instance variable on your view controller

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3
                          delay:0
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear
                     animations:^{
                         viewToMaximize.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.1, 1.1);
                         viewToUnmaximize.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                     }];

    _maximizedView = viewToMaximize;
}
```

Also, `CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1, 1)` will scale the view to its original size, so I bumped the scale up in my code snippet.

Comment: if he's trying to scale the carousel, then viewToMaximize should not be recognizer.view here, that's the view that the gesture is attached to - most likely self.view.

Comment: At the end of the post, @user2828182 stated that he was trying to scale `view` (which the gesture recognizer was attached to), *not* the entire carousel.

Comment: Thank you Austin so much! Your solution really worked. I had to increase the scale to 1.45 to get the required size because with the scale of 1 nothing happens which is kind of weird. I declared maximizedView as a property like this:                                                      @property (nonatomic, strong)  UIView* maximizedView; Is this right or should I do it differently? Thanks again Austin!

Comment: Well, I noticed that if I tap the current view the second time it shrinks back to its previous size but if I tap it the third time and to infinity, it keeps shifting between the new size and the old size quickly like a beating heart or something. How can I go about this issue?

Comment: Edit the code so that it doesn't try to maximize and already maximized view

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding this correctly you want to transform the UIView that you tapped on, which should be the carousel?

Assuming you added the tap gesture recognizer to self.view, then this is how you get the view you just tapped on:

```
- (void)tapToMaximize:(UITapGestureRecognizer*)recognizer
{
    UIView *view = [self.view hitTest:[recognizer locationInView:self.view] withEvent:nil];
    // you can now check to see if this view is the carousel
}
```

Once you know whether or not you tapped on the carousel, you can store it, pass it on to another class, transform it, or anything you like.

Comment: Thank you bpercevic for taking the bother to answer my question. It works but if I enlarge one view, it doesn't go back to its original size once I tap another view to enlarge. Austin got it right for me. Thank you both. Really appreciate it.